# how to get `dataProvider ` with each product_id

Tags: yii

i have order table  where in product_id is string Like 10,11,12,13. And have Product table with this id.
how to get     `dataProvider` with each product_id
My code is

```
 public function getProducts($id){
    $idarray = explode(',', $id);

    $dataProviderProduct = Array();
    foreach($idarray as $i=>$id){

        $dataProviderProduct[$i]=new CActiveDataProvider('Product',
                array(  'criteria'=>array(
                            'condition'=>'id=:id',
                            'params'=>array(':id' => $id),

                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array( 'pageSize'=>10),
                    )
                );
    }
    return $dataProviderProduct;
}
```

But this is wrong code

Answer (score 0):

Use [addInCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) like this:

```
$idarray = explode(',', $id);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('id', $idarray);
$data = ModelName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: yes you ar right. but if my Order table contain prodict_id "33,33,34";

Comment: i will have 2 product instead 3

Comment: I don't undrstand what you mean? where is problem if id is not unique?

Comment: in my View i add ListView for each ORDER for Authenticated User(Order history). for each item I add Gridview for ordered products. And if order's product_id is "33, 33, 34" Grid view show online 2 rows in table, for id=>33 and for id=>34. And, as you can see will be shown 2 products intead  3. that is my problem